# Cannot update combobox selected index from the view to the viewmodel

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, combobox

Using the MVVM pattern, I've bound the SelectedIndex property of a combo box to a variable in my view model.  I can change the combo box selection programmatically from the view model; however, when the user makes a selection from the interface (view), the view model variable is not updated.

Here is the XAML (snipet):

`<ComboBox Width="100"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
         SelectedIndex="{Binding GroupSortIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <ComboBoxItem Content="Appearance"/>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="Created"/>
         <ComboBoxItem Content="Name"/>
</ComboBox>`

Here is a portion of the view model:

`public int GroupSortIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(GroupSortIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GroupSortIndexProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupSortIndexProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GroupSortIndex", typeof(int),
        typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(-1));`

What do I need to do to have GroupSortIndex updated when the user makes a selection from the IU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, The `SelectedIndex` property looks has a bug. i was this problem and i solved it by changing the `SelectedIndex` to `SelectedItem`.

Change XAML SelectedIndex to SelectedItem:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourOptionsList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}" />
```

Somewhere you must set the DataContext of your Window to reference the collection from your `XAML`.

and in your `ViewModel` write this:

```
public List<String> YourOptionsList { get { return (int)GetValue(YourOptionsListProperty); } set { SetValue(YourOptionsListProperty, value); } }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty YourOptionsListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("YourOptionsList", typeof(List<String>), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<String>()));

public string SelectedOption { get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedOptionProperty); } set { SetValue(SelectedOptionProperty, value); } }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedOptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedOption", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata("none");


  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    YourOptionsList =new List<String>();
    YourOptionsList.Add("Appearance");
    YourOptionsList.Add("Created");
    YourOptionsList.Add("Name");
  }
```

Comment: I almost up voted you for your first point, but then I noticed your mistake and then I nearly down voted you. I therefore decided that I won't vote either way, but you'd better fix your code example before someone does down vote your answer. It won't work as it stands because the `SelectedOption` is an `int` and the collection items are `string`s.

Comment: I had to bind the `ComboBox` to a collection via `ItemsSource`.  In my original question, I had defined `ComboBoxItems` which does not work with `SelectedIndex`.  Thanks.